# ubuntu как передать файлы с одного сервера на другой внутри домена с сохранением прав

Tags: windows, ubuntu, сервер, samba

есть два файловых сервера в одном домене, но при передачу через какой-нибудь rsync с атрибутами --xattr --acl права не передаются, а заменяются на стандартные то есть владелец root, группа root, а о правах пользователей, которые создавали файлы или папки - ничего, однако если вручную создать от пользователя на втором сервере файл, то он создается с правами пользователя домена.

сами сервера на ubuntu, сделаны через samba, файлы и папки создаются в windows, так же все права указываются средствами windows.

в smb.conf указано следующее:

```
# winbind:
idmap config * : range = 5000-20000
idmap config * : backend = tdb
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind enum users = yes
winbind use default domain = yes

template shell = /bin/bash
winbind refresh tickets = yes
vfs objects = acl_xattr
map acl inherit = yes
store dos attributes = yes
```

и на первом, и на втором сервере. передавать файлы пробовал через rsync и unison.

Comment: Виртуалка на винде, примонтировать первую убунту на диск Z:, вторую на диск Y:, а потом пригласить `robocopy`.

Comment: Или тебе на постоянку нужно копировать?

Comment: на постоянку, файлы то копируются без проблем, а вот параметры безопасности, которые я указывал уже на windows - нет

Comment: А `tar --acls` помогает?